# Add sum of squares of model parameters to loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Adding sum of squares of model weights is known to be a regularization method that prevents overfitting of the deep learning models.
Currently I have this loss function for my model which is implemented in `pytorch`:

```
lossfunc = nn.NLLLoss(ignore_index=0)
```

Then, I compute the loss during training as follows:

```
 ... 
loss = lossfunc(out_perm, dec_pp[:,1:])
```

I want the regularized loss to look like:

```
loss = lossfunc(out_perm, dec_pp[:,1:])+sum_square_wights(enc)+sum_square_wights(dec)
```

But don't know how to implement `sum_square_wights` function. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, If you have all the weights in a matrix, then you could write a custom function to calculate the sum of the square of weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to  L2 regularization. If that is indeed the case, L2 regularization is already added to [optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html)  in torch (SGD, Adam etc) and you can control it using a non-zero value for `weight_decay` in optimizer's parameter.

As for as L1 regularization is concerned, something like this should do the job:

```
l1_criterion = nn.L1Loss(size_average=False)
l1_reg_loss = 0
for param in model.parameters():
    l1_reg_loss += l1_criterion (param)

lambda = 0.0005
loss += lambda * l1_reg_loss
```

Comment: I had no idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, as @asymptote mentioned, and as can be seen in Bishop's PRML book:

> The particular case of a quadratic regularizer is called ridge
>   regression (Hoerl and Kennard, 1970). In the context of neural
>   networks, this approach is known as weight decay.

For the curious reader, we can regularize the loss function with L2 as follows:

```
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
lmbd = 1e-8  # for custom L2 regularization
loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)

reg_loss = None
for param in model.parameters():
    if reg_loss is None:
        reg_loss = torch.sum(param ** 2)
    else:
        reg_loss = reg_loss + param.norm(2) ** 2

loss += lmbd * reg_loss
```